# How to resolve InvalidUseOfMatchers exception in Java - Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I have been working on the unit test for a class ProcessorImpl. In this class I created a static void call from another class, MetadataUtils. In MetadataUtils class I had:

```
public class MetadataUtils {    
    private static Metadata metadata  = new Metadata();
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    public static void setMetadataFromHeader(String header) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        metadata = mapper.readValue(header, Metadata.class);        
    }
...
}
```

In my ProcessorImpl class I called

```
MetadataUtils.setMetadataFromHeader(getHeader(CsbConstants.METADATA).toString());
```

In ProcessorImplTest (unit test) class I wrote:

```
PowerMockito.when(processor, method(ProcessorImpl.class, "getHeader"))
        .withArguments(CsbConstants.METADATA)
        .thenReturn(Mockito.any(String.class));
MetadataUtils metadataUtils = Mockito.mock(MetadataUtils.class);
Mockito.doNothing().when(metadataUtils).setMetadataFromHeader(Mockito.any(String.class));
```

But I got exception InvalidUseOfMachers. Could you help please to resolve it?

Comment: In which line exactly  did the exception happen?

Comment: in line  MetadataUtils metadataUtils = Mockito.mock(MetadataUtils.class);

Comment: When you tell a mock to return something, you need to tell it what to return. Telling it to return anything it wants doesn't make much sense. And when you ask about an exception, alays post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I have just changed my doNothing: Mockito.doReturn("Test").when(metadataUtils).setMetadataFromHeader(Mockito.any(String.class)); but I got the same error.Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, one problem at a time, right? We are not aiming for moving targets.

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito.when(mock.doSomething()).thenReturn(...)` should be stubbed with an actual value, it can not return Mockito.any(...)

Comment: Thank you for your interest and help. I have just changed :

Comment: PowerMockito.when(processor, method(ProcessorImpl.class, "getHeader"))
        .withArguments(CsbConstants.METADATA)
        .thenReturn("Test"); but now I got NullPointerException

Comment: I personally don't like `PowerMockito` too much, I just use `Whitebox` to set internal values. If you need to use static methods just wrap them in an object, mock this object and stub it with the desired values.

Comment: I agree with @michaeak. Don't use powermock if you don't need it. PowerMock should be the last resort. Sometimes a small code change can make the class testable without the use of powermock.